# how to prove $m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1 \pmod{mn}$ where m and n are relatively prime?

Tags: congruences

I do not know how to prove this question: $m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1 \pmod {mn}$ where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly is the question?  Your equation is not always true, and it's not always false.

Comment: I think it should be $m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1$.

Comment: yes. I'm not easy to use this website..thanks

Comment: It takes some practice to get the formatting correct, @SayantanKoley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Can you prove:

$$m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1 \pmod {m}$$ and $$m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1 \pmod {n}?$$

Comment: Yes of course From Euler's theorem i can say so...and then applying gcd(m,n)=1 gives the solution...thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since $\gcd(m, n) = 1$, so by Euler's theorem
$$m^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$$
and
$$n^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \mod m$$
But
$$m^{\phi(n)} \equiv 0 \mod m$$
and
$$n^{\phi(m)} \equiv 0 \mod n$$
Thus,
$$m^{\phi(n)} + n^{\phi(m)} \equiv (1 + 0) \mod n  \equiv 1 \mod n$$
and
$$m^{\phi(n)} + n^{\phi(m)} \equiv (1 + 0) \mod m  \equiv 1 \mod m$$
Hence,
$$m^{\phi(n)} + n^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \mod mn$$

Answer (score 3):

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, it suffices to prove that
$$
m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1\mod{m},\qquad m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1\mod{n}.
$$
But now this follows trivially, since $m^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\mod{n}$ by [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) (and likewise for $n$).

Comment: By the definition of $\phi$? I'm pretty sure that isn't a definition but a result...

Comment: You're right, I was getting ahead of myself.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ It is simply $\,\overbrace{(0,1)}^{\large m^{\large \phi(n)}}+ \overbrace{(1,0)}^{\large n^{\large \phi(m)}}\, =\, \overbrace{(1,1)}^{\large1}\ $ in $\ \Bbb Z/m \times \Bbb Z/n\overset{\rm CRT}\cong \Bbb Z/mn\ $ using [Euler's Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)

Comment: yes brother @Bill